# How do I bridge connections in Debian?

Tags: linux, networking, debian

In windows I can select *Local Area Connection* and *Wireless Network Connection*, right click and select *Bridge Connections*

How can I achieve the same effect in Linux? (Debian to be exact)

Pretty much I want *Computer B* to connect to *Computer A* via ethernet cable. Well *Computer A* is connected wirelessly. Allowing *Computer B* to get on the internet.

**== UPDATE ==**

I've enabled IP forwarding and used the following iptables command:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlan0 -j MASQUERADE
```

I'm still unable to access the internet from *Computer B* though.

Comment: do you using gnome/kde ? network manager have a master to make shared connection, if you like windows way...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a list of commands that you need to type in:

on computer A

1. `iptables -t nat -F` (this will flush iptables nat section, everything that was there before)
2. `sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` (this will enable ip forwarding)
3. `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s IP_ADDRES_COMP_B -j MASQUERADE` (this will nat eveything that comes from computer b

on computer B

1. check that default gateway of this computer is COMPUTER A.
2. check DNS servers on computer A , (cat /etc/resolv.conf) and set same on computer B.
3. in case of trubles with DNS servers on computer A, use 8.8.8.8 as primary and 8.8.4.4 as secondary

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [ArchWiki article](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Internet_Share). You should just need the **Enable NAT** and **Manually adding an ip** sections, but if that doesn't work, then check out the rest.
*Edited: Forgot a section.*

Comment: I've followed the steps to Enable NAT but i'm still having trouble. See edit.

Comment: Check out the second section listed. Sorry. (If that doesn't work, just read the rest and check out some of the other links and relevant manpages.)

Answer (score 0):

From the debian wiki - [Bridge Connections](http://wiki.debian.org/BridgeNetworkConnections)

First, you should install `bridge-utils` package. Rest of the article is pretty straightforward and explains much about how to set up working bridge connection to another device.

With the abovementioned `iptables` command you just routed *Computer B* to *Computer A*'s wireless adapter. But *Computer B* cannot use that directly because it lacks the needed rules. It doesn't know where to go or what to do with it, so to speak.